# Instagram API: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, api, instagram

I am receiving the following error though I don't really know why: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Here is the code block that is throwing the error:

```
//get elseCount
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/crookedspaces/media/recent/?count=100&access_token=MYTOKEN",
    success: function(data) {
        confirm("Else Count running");
        for (var e = 0; e < imageCount; e++) {
            var igUID = data.data[e].user.id;
            if(igUID !== "16741082") {
                //confirm("Else count: " + elseCount + ".");
                //console.log("Else portion of code ran " + elseCount + " time(s).");
                ++elseCount;
            }
        }
        console.log("Else count:" + elseCount + ".");                
    }
});
```

Comment: are you replacing MYTOKEN with your actual token in your code?

Comment: @sushanthreddy data.data.user.id; should pull up the user id of whome ever tagged the image they uploaded.

Comment: @monotheist yes MYTOKEN is being replaced

Comment: Can you put this URL in the browser like chrome "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/crookedspaces/media/recent/?count=100&access_token=MYTOKEN" and paste the results, replace the token accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is getting data from different users

So use this data.data[0].user.id

If you want you can put the index in a loop, but first try the above it should work.

Also replace
Replace for (var e = 0; e < imageCount; e++)  with

```
for (var e = 0; e < data.data.length; e++)
```

Comment: monotheist, I have changed the code to your suggestion but am still getting the same error.

Comment: are you getting the exact same error again, can you expand "user" and show us the screen shot.

Comment: Alright, I altered my code again, and using [0] or [1] or whatever does not return the error, however if I use my variable (e) the error occurs.

Comment: Updated my answer, please try the new one.

Comment: This works, however it only returns 60 results, but for the purpose of my question it is answer, just not the way I'd like. Instagram API problem moreseo than coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not reading your json object properly..

what does **console.log(data)** look like ??

Look's like you have to read the data like

```
data.data[0].user.id   // To access the first item in the array
```

If you want to use any other id of the user then replace 1 with that index..

To iterate and use those value you can use a $.each loop on daata.data

Comment: console.log(data);

pulls a rather large array of 60 items.

Comment: A couple of array items should help

Comment: here is a [screencap](http://crookedspaces.com/images/misc/TypeErrorArray_SO.png) of 2 parts of the array.

Comment: Try accessing the variable like this  data.data[0].user.id      ...... i.e, if you want to access the 1st item in the array and so on

Comment: Try console.log(data.data[0].user.id) and check what you get

Comment: I successfully return the user's id. It appears that the error is happening somewhere while using my variable (e).